# Network Load Balancing Servers cannot communicate with each other

Tags: windows-server-2003, load-balancing

With Windows 2003, if I try to ping one Loadbalanced server with the other it is getting a request time out. Is this how it should be?

However, from a client - we are able to ping each load balancing server individually and the VIP too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design with NLB when using Unicast with a single NIC. Take at look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/898867 as it gives more details on the problem as well as a registry change that should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do these servers have dual nics?  Are you trying to ping the public adapter from the private heartbeat adapter maybe?  Is your server having issues?